# Unable to download file from a newly created torrent using monotorrent

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, bittorrent, monotorrent

I used the following code for creating torrent in monotorrent solution. But references are missing for "RawTrackerTier".I am able to create torrent when i comment that lines of code but i am unable to download file from that created torrent. Is it because of the missing reference or any other problem in the solution?If it is ,can anyone provide the missing references?
please help me!!

```
public void CreateTorrent(string path, string savePath)
{
    // The class used for creating the torrent
    TorrentCreator c = new TorrentCreator();

    // Add one tier which contains two trackers
    RawTrackerTier tier = new RawTrackerTier(); // MISSING REFERENCE HERE
    tier.Add("http://localhost/announce");

    c.Announces.Add(tier);
    c.Comment = "This is the comment";
    c.CreatedBy = "Doug using " + VersionInfo.ClientVersion;
    c.Publisher = "www.aaronsen.com";

    // Set the torrent as private so it will not use DHT or peer exchange
    // Generally you will not want to set this.
    c.Private = true;

    // Every time a piece has been hashed, this event will fire. It is an
    // asynchronous event, so you have to handle threading yourself.
    c.Hashed += delegate(object o, TorrentCreatorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current File is {0}% hashed", e.FileCompletion);
        Console.WriteLine("Overall {0}% hashed", e.OverallCompletion);
        Console.WriteLine("Total data to hash: {0}", e.OverallSize);
    };

    // ITorrentFileSource can be implemented to provide the TorrentCreator
    // with a list of files which will be added to the torrent metadata.
    // The default implementation takes a path to a single file or a path
    // to a directory. If the path is a directory, all files will be
    // recursively added

    ITorrentFileSource fileSource = new TorrentFileSource(path);

    // Create the torrent file and save it directly to the specified path
    // Different overloads of 'Create' can be used to save the data to a Stream
    // or just return it as a BEncodedDictionary (its native format) so it can be
    // processed in memory
    c.Create(fileSource, savePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of `MonoTorrent` on nuget (version 0.9.0) is quite old and appears to have only single-tier announce support.  If you're using that version, this code might work:

```
// The class used for creating the torrent
TorrentCreator c = new TorrentCreator();

// Add tracker(s)
c.Announces.Add("http://localhost/announce");
```

The latest version of `monotorrent` is available (code only) at [github](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent).  You could try downloading the library source and building it yourself.